# Deploying Nuxtjs on AWS Amplify Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, nuxt.js

I'm deploying my `nuxtjs` app on AWS Amplify Console using the following build settings:

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

and for the redirect rules, I've the following:

```
[
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Everything works well and I can access the SPA app. But when I do a refresh from a nested URL (eg: `example.com/users/23`), I'm being redirected to the `example.com/index.html` page with a 'This page count not be found' error message. I know this is probably because of the History mode of the vue router. (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

How can I modify the rewrite rules to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. It was:

```
[ 
   { 
      "source":"</^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
      "status":"200",
      "target":"index.html",
      "condition":null
   }
]
```